# BouncyCastle invalid parameter passed to AES init

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle

I have a .net framework 4.5.2 project in which AES 256/GCM/NO padding implementation has to be performed. I found out that framework doesn't support GCM directly hence I tried using BouncyCastle. While passing the params it looks like something is wrong being passed to initialization. Also I wanted to make the Keysize as 256 bit . I [took this](https://kashifsoofi.github.io/cryptography/aes-in-csharp-using-bouncycastle/) page as reference

Below is the code which I'm trying :

```
public class BouncyCastleCustom:ICipherParameters
    {
        private const string ALGORITHM = "AES";
        private const byte AesIvSize = 16;
        private const byte GcmTagSize = 16; // in bytes
        private readonly CipherMode _cipherMode = CipherMode.GCM;

        //private const string _cipherMode = "GCM";

        private readonly string _algorithm = ALGORITHM;

        public string Encrypt(string plainText, byte[] key)
        {

            var random = new SecureRandom();
            var iv = random.GenerateSeed(AesIvSize);
            var keyParameters = CreateKeyParameters(key, iv, GcmTagSize * 8);
            var cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher(_algorithm);
            cipher.Init(true, keyParameters);/*System.ArgumentException: 'invalid parameter passed to AES init - Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.AeadParameters'*/


            var plainTextData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            var cipherText = cipher.DoFinal(plainTextData);

            return PackCipherData(cipherText, iv);
        }

        public string Decrypt(string cipherText, byte[] key)
        {
            var (encryptedBytes, iv, tagSize) = UnpackCipherData(cipherText);
            var keyParameters = CreateKeyParameters(key, iv, tagSize * 8);
            var cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher(_algorithm);
            cipher.Init(false, keyParameters);

            var decryptedData = cipher.DoFinal(encryptedBytes);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);
        }

        private ICipherParameters CreateKeyParameters(byte[] key, byte[] iv, int macSize)
        {
            var keyParameter = new KeyParameter(key);
            if (_cipherMode == CipherMode.CBC)
            {
                return new ParametersWithIV(keyParameter, iv);
            }
            else if (_cipherMode == CipherMode.GCM)
            {
                return new AeadParameters(keyParameter, macSize, iv);
            }

            throw new Exception("Unsupported cipher mode");
        }

        private string PackCipherData(byte[] encryptedBytes, byte[] iv)
        {
            var dataSize = encryptedBytes.Length + iv.Length + 1;
            if (_cipherMode == CipherMode.GCM)
                dataSize += 1;

            var index = 0;
            var data = new byte[dataSize];
            data[index] = AesIvSize;
            index += 1;
            if (_cipherMode == CipherMode.GCM)
            {
                data[index] = GcmTagSize;
                index += 1;
            }

            Array.Copy(iv, 0, data, index, iv.Length);
            index += iv.Length;
            Array.Copy(encryptedBytes, 0, data, index, encryptedBytes.Length);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
        }

        private (byte[], byte[], byte) UnpackCipherData(string cipherText)
        {
            var index = 0;
            var cipherData = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            byte ivSize = cipherData[index];
            index += 1;

            byte tagSize = 0;
            if (_cipherMode == CipherMode.GCM)
            {
                tagSize = cipherData[index];
                index += 1;
            }

            byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];
            Array.Copy(cipherData, index, iv, 0, ivSize);
            index += ivSize;

            byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[cipherData.Length - index];
            Array.Copy(cipherData, index, encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
            return (encryptedBytes, iv, tagSize);
        }

        public enum CipherMode   //cannot access BouncyCastle inbuilt CipherMode
        {
            CBC,
            GCM
        }
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            BouncyCastleCustom aes = new BouncyCastleCustom();
            var encrypted = aes.Encrypt("testDemo", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mysmallkey1234551298765134567890"));
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted testDemo: " + encrypted);
            string decrypted = aes.Decrypt(encrypted, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mysmallkey1234551298765134567890"));
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted: " + decrypted);

        }
```

Comment: If you read the [linked code](https://github.com/kashifsoofi/crypto-sandbox/blob/master/dotnet/src/Sandbox.Crypto/AesBcCrypto.cs#L25) carefully, you will notice that `_algorithm` specifies not only the algorithm, but also mode and padding. This is missing in your code.

Comment: _Also I wanted to make the Keysize as 256 bit._ - You are already using a 32 bytes = 256 bits key (i.e. AES 256).